# Using Dropzone.js in MVC Editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dropzone.js

I am facing some issues in using dropzone.js in MVC 5 editor templates. I have a partial view with the complete form, which is very big, and in that partial view I call an editor template, where I am using dropzone.js. On form submit (implemented using custom button and jquery.form.js), model is posted back and one of the property of model is files.

Editor template code:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="dropzone" id="filesDropZone">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.attachmentFiles, new { type = "file", multiple = "true" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.attachmentFiles)
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS code:

```
Dropzone.options.filesDropZone = 
        {
            url: '@ViewBag.ActionUrl',
            autoDiscover: false,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            paramName: "attachmentFiles",
            uploadMultiple: true
        };
```

Now the two issues I am facing are:

1. This code does not work in chrome (I am not able to drop files in dropzone) while it works in IE10. I have tried using `document.ready` or using `new Dropzone` but same result.
2. on click of save button, an action is called which contains the complete model but when I use dropzone, I have to write `processQueue` on click of button and that action is called twice. One with attachments and no other data and once with data and not attachments. What I want is, it is called just once with all form data including attachments.

Any help is appreciated. I am even open to using any other better library or writing custom code if this is the only way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the form to be submitted, load the files and then submit it.
The reason why the form is submitted twice is because the function: `processQueue()` of dropzone also submit the form... so you have to submit it either using `processQueue()` or `form.submit` (in case there are no attachments)

```
$("button[type=submit]").on("click", function (e) {
    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.

    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    if (form.valid() == true) {
        if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {

            for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
            }

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        } else {
            form.submit();
            //myDropzone.uploadFiles([]); //send empty
        }
    }
});
```